# boost asioサーバーでのルート設定について

Tags: html, c++, boost

boost asioサーバーにおいて、ルートをリクエストURL(htmlファイルなど)にしたいのですが、調べた限り、その方法が載っていません。誰かご教授いただけませんか？

【追記】
例えばlocalhost:3000/hoge.htmlにアクセスされたらhoge.htmlを、localhost:3000/fuga.htmlにアクセスされたらfuga.htmlを表示するみたいな感じです。
https://qiita.com/ritukiii/items/8173ff98f31c2f76b39a
この記事で言う、「リクエスト毎に処理を分けてみる」と「HTMLを表示してみる」をかけ合わせたようなやつのC++版をしたいです。

Comment: 質問者さんのいう「ルート」とは何で、「ルートをリクエストURLにしたい」とはどのような行為なのでしょうか？ 求めていることのヒントになるようなコード片など提示できないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

[Boost.Asio公式ドキュメントに記載されているHTTP Server](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp11_examples.http_server)であれば、`server`コンストラクタの第３引数`<doc_root>`を設定するだけです。

Comment: server.hppを新たにインクルードするということですか？無知ですいません。

Comment: @Jin_2004 サンプルなので、インクルードしてそのまま使うのではなく、コードを理解しでご自身で書くべきです。